# How to construct a find statement using multiple bash script arguments

Tags: bash, find

To find a file containing more than one case-insensitive search term, I'm doing:

```bash
find . -iname "*first*" -iname "*second*"
```

I'd like to turn this into a utility script, so that I can just type

```bash
./myfind.sh first second
```

However, since brace expansion happens before variable expansion, I can't do:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
find . {-iname "*${*}*"}
```

Note that the number of arguments will be variable, so I can't hard-code just two `-iname` flags.

I've been warned against using bash `eval` as a workaround. Is there a better approach I can take?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The typical solution to this problem is to build an argument list in an array and then expand the array in double quotes to preserve each argument.

(note: concatentation with `-o` is only required if you mean to match first OR second - if you want to match first AND second then remove the `-o`)

```
#!/bin/bash
args=( "-iname" "$1" ) # set the first iname option
shift # discard the first argument
for arg ; do
  # for each remaining argument, concatenate additional -iname options with -o
  args+=( "-o" "-iname" "$arg" )
done

find . "${args[@]}"
```

Then your invocation might look like:

```
# single quote each search pattern to prevent any interpretation by the shell
./myfind.sh '*first*' '*second*'
```

Comment: If you mean in the invocation you could assume the `*` is desired and hardcode it - for example `args=( "-iname" "*$1*" )` and `args+=( "-o" "-iname" "*$arg*" )` and then the invocation is just `./myfind.sh first second`. Quotes will still be required at invocation depending on the data (for example if you want to find a file like `*hello world*` then you will have to quote `'hello world'` but most of the time you'll be okay without quotes.

Comment: Just add the `*` to the array: `( -iname "*$1" )`. Whether or not you need quotes on the command line depends on the actual argument: e.g., `myfind.sh first "a b"` or `my find.sh first a\ b` both pass *two* arguments to your script, where `myfind.sh first a b` would pass three.

Comment: Aha, this is perfect, thank you so much! I had at first assumed that there was a reason the asterisk had to be on the command line, but now I see it's easy to add in to the script

Comment: Btw I've simplified it a little as `for arg; do args+=( "-iname" "*$arg*" ); shift; done`, to avoid repetition (so that there does not need to be the initial `args=`)

Comment: Yes that's probably a better match to your question, although you don't need `shift`. I didn't notice that you meant to match files containing all the patterns. Usually people search for files containing any of the patterns so I added a bit of boilerplate to get the `-o` in there but if you don't need it then your modification is good for your use case.